# Creating a recursive query in SQL

Tags: sql, recursion, sql-server-2012

I have data like this:

- Person A has a relationship with Person B, and person A has a relationship with Person C
- Person B has a relationship with D and E.

[image]

I want to view result in group in SQL Server (A, B ,C,...) and (B,D,E,...)

[image]

I have tried looking recursive but not getting this to implement.

I need to do this in SQL.

Thanks for the help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve without using recursive cte. Try the following using `string_agg` and `concat`. here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c24f8155b564b2ca40b7b3193528c915).

```
select
  concat(columnA, ', ', string_agg(columnB, ', ')) as columnC
from myTable
group by
  columnA
```

output:

```
|columnC|
*-------*
|A, B, C|
|B, D, E|
```

In SQL Server 2012 you can use `XML PATH` as following

```
select
  concat(
  columnA, ',',
  stuff((
            select ', ' + columnB
            from myTable m1
            where m1.columnA = m2.columnA
            for xml path('')
        ), 1, 1, ''
    )) as columnC
from myTable m2
group by
  columnA
```

Comment: tks your help. Can you help me replace string_agg in sql server 2012 or 2008?

Comment: tks for your help